# Django Template Not Receiving Context Object

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, render

I'm trying to implement a simple sign up form and slightly tearing my hair out. For some reason, the view doesn't seem to be properly passing the context object I pass it (regardless of what it is.)

here's my code:

urls.py

```
path(r"signup/", client_views.signup_view, name="page-signup")
```

views.py

```
def signup_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('page-index')
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', context=context)
```

registration/signup.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}


{% block header %}
Sign Up
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

I've confirmed it's

1. generating the form properly as html
2. it's also definitely rendering the correct template
3. doesn't pass any context even if it's just a string or something
4. doesn't work with any forms
5. doesn't work in other templates, implying to me it's in the view

I'm sure this is some stupid mistake but I've been tearing my hair out over this - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It was because my template tags didn't match up

Specifically, I wrote:

`{% bloc content %}`

instead of

`{% block body %}`